# How to write configure.ac and Makefile.am for freeglut?

Tags: opengl, makefile, autotools, freeglut, pkg-config

I want to use freeglut for my project.

In my configure.ac it looks like this, it worked like this for SDL so I just replaced some potions and hoped it works for freeglut as well but it does not. So what am I doing wrong?

```
# Check for freeglut
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([FREEGLUT], [freeglut >= 3.0])
AC_SUBST(FREEGLUT_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(FREEGLUT_LIBS)
```

Also what do I have to write into Makefile.am? For SDL it looks like this:

```
INCLUDES = @SDL_CFLAGS@
LDADD = @SDL_LIBS@
```

Comment: Do you need FreeGLUT or a GLUT?

Answer (score 3):

Correcting/adding to ptomato's answer:

Short: in reality freeglut is glut, so do:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([glut], [glutInit])
```

Explanation: freeglut is a replacement for older/unfree implementations of The OpenGL Utility Toolkit (GLUT). In today's distributions freeglut is installed as a replacement for these older/unfree GLUT installations. This is done by setting the `--enable-replace-glut` configure option of freeglut. As a result the library is called `libglut` instead of `libfreeglut`. Take a look for example at [Ubuntu's freeglut package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/i386/freeglut3/filelist); it contains `/usr/lib/libglut.so.3`.

And to support older distributions, which install freeglut as libfreeglut instead of libglut, you would need to check for that, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Pkg-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) is a program that looks up the necessary compiler flags and linker flags for a library. `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([NAME], [libraries])` is an autoconf macro that looks up the flags for `libraries` and puts them into two variables, `NAME_CFLAGS` and `NAME_LIBS`. Not all libraries support it.

In order to support pkg-config, libraries must install a .pc file. Looking at [freeglut's source code](http://freeglut.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/freeglut/trunk/freeglut/freeglut/) it seems that there isn't one, so I conclude it doesn't support pkg-config.

What you should do when a library doesn't support pkg-config, is look at [its documentation](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) to see whether it mentions any compiler flags and linker flags you should use. I can't find mention of this anywhere.

Since that fails, the next best thing is just to assume that the library doesn't need any extra compiler flags, and only one linker flag: `-l<name>`, in this case `-lfreeglut`. You can also use an autoconf macro to check this for you automatically. You can add this to your `configure.ac` like so:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([freeglut], [glutInit])
```

This will automatically add `-lfreeglut` to `LIBS` if the freeglut library is present, so you shouldn't have to write anything extra in your `Makefile.am`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dnl Check for GLUT
GLUT_CFLAGS=""
GLUT_LIBS=-lglut
glut_enabled=yes
AC_ARG_WITH([glut],
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-glut=DIR],
            [glut install directory])],
    [GLUT_CFLAGS="-I$withval/include"
     GLUT_LIBS="-L$withval/lib -lglut"])
AC_CHECK_HEADER([GL/glut.h],
        [],
        [glut_enabled=no])
AC_CHECK_LIB([glut],
        [glutInit],
        [],
        [glut_enabled=no])
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..